# Spring:Ambiguity constructor argument types with single constructor

Tags: java, xml, spring, javabeans

I have following spring bean configuration,

```
<bean id="Handler"
    class="com.XYZ.Handler"
    scope="singleton" lazy-init="false">
    <constructor-arg ref="FirstCheck" />
    <constructor-arg ref="SecondCheck" />
    <constructor-arg ref="ThirdCheck" />
</bean>
```

In the "Handler" class there is only one constructor with three arguments of the types mentioned above.But i'm getting the following error for the 3rd param(index 2).

"Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 2 of type [com.XYZ.ThirdCheck]: Ambiguous constructor argument types - did you specify the correct bean references as constructor arguments?"

Comment: Post the related classes

Comment: Add the `index` attribute to your `construct-arg` element. Spring tries to determine which constructor to call by checking the types (if you don't give the index) if there are multiple arguments of the same type you have to include an `index` attribute in your configuration.

Comment: @M.Deinum : I tried adding index like this, <constructor-arg index="0" ref="FirstCheck" /> .But it didn seem to work.

Comment: Post the code and actual stacktrace.